# How to repeat the invoice number on each pages of an invoice PDF

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I need to show the invoice number in all pages of a same invoices when I generate the invoice PDF for downloading or printing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template id="external_layout_header_inherited" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="inside">
        <div t-if="o.number">Ref.: <span t-field="o.number"/></div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: This will put the `<div>` element on every report that has an `external_layout_header` and has a field named number as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can put and span in the header or in the footer like in the example above

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
          <span class="page"/>/<span class="topage"/>
     </div>
 </div>
```